# Is there a design pattern for this specific small problem described below?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Main loop is a recipient for two kinds of messages. First type message is frequent and work for this message is done in main loop thread. Second type message is rare, and upon its arrival parallel thread is awoken to do work for second type message. Work for second type message can take a lot of time and there is a possibility, that new message (or multiple messages) of second type arrives during this time. Occurance of second type message should be noted and after previous threaded work is done, new work should start, but only once no matter how many second type messages was received.

```
           main thd           work thd
               |
 2nd message-> |-->do work-------
               |                |
               |                |
 2nd message-> |                |
               |                |
 2nd message-> |                |
               |<-- end ---------             
               |-->do work-------
               |                |
               |                |
               |                |
               |                |
               |                |
               |<-- end ---------             
               |
               |
```

For now i was thinking of using condition variable for waking of second type message thread, and a flag for reporting arrival of new second type messages.

Is there some proper design patern for such problem?

regards

Comment: The message-filtering is a form of "rate-limiting", though I don't know if there's a *design* pattern for that specifically; it's more of a concept. The threading sounds like something that would be really well suited to having some form of task executor for threads, or possibly even just using the `asio` library

Comment: Search for "Thread pool with a work queue"

Comment: As a matter of fact i am using thread pool build with asio library :). But there is a thing, i do not want to run 'threaded job' for every 2nd type message. In the case shown abowe while first job is going, two subsequent 2nd messages should trigger only one new threaded job.